# How to access values in groupby dataframe with multiple labels?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the values inside dataframe that has been grouped.

I grouped payment data with time the person borrowed the money and months it took for the person to pay and summed the amount they paid. My goal is to find the list of months it took for people to pay back.

For example, how can I know the list of 'month_taken' when start_yyyymm is 201807?

```
payment_sum_monthly = 
payment_data.groupby(['start_yyyymm','month_taken']) 
[['amount']].sum()
```

If I use R and put the payment data in data.table form, I can find out the list of month_taken by

```
payment_sum_monthly[start_yyyymm == '201807',month_taken]
```

How can I do this in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_date = payment_data['start_yyyymm'] == "201807"
```

It should give you all the entities that has `'start_yyyymm'` is 201807. Then to call those entities, you can code following:

```
date_set = payment_data[is_date].copy()
payment_sum_monthly = date_set .groupby('month_taken').aggregate(sum)
payment_sum_monthly
```

And if you need one more condition you can do following:

```
condition2 = payment_data['column name'] == condition
payment_data[is_date & condition2]
```

I hope I got your question right and it helps